# Exchange name in Pika exchange_declare callback

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I try to use the exchange name in my `exchange_declare` callback. I use the `SelectConnection` adapter for asynchronous requests in Pika.

My idea is to first build lists of exchanges, queues and bindings in my program. I then dispatch multiple exchange and queue declarations to Pika, and create bindings as soon as the needed queues and exchanges for each binding have got their DeclareOK messages.

This means I need to know the names of exchanges and queues in my callbacks so that I can correlate them with the bindings to create.

Something like this:

```
print "Create A"
channel.exchange_declare(callback=on_exchange, exchange="exchangeA")
print "Create B"
channel.exchange_declare(callback=on_exchange, exchange="exchangeB")

def on_exchange(response):
  # How do I know if this was exchangeA or exchangeB ?
  print "Exchange declared"
  print response
```

This gives the following output, which clearly shows that the exchanges are declared first and callbacks triggered later (as expected):

```
Create A
Create B
Exchange declared
<METHOD(['method=<Exchange.DeclareOk>', 'channel_number=1', 'frame_type=1'])>
Exchange declared
<METHOD(['method=<Exchange.DeclareOk>', 'channel_number=1', 'frame_type=1'])>
```

I have figured out that `response` is of type [pika.frame.Method](https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.12/_modules/pika/frame.html) but how do I go from there? Are the exchanges perhaps guaranteed to be declared in order?

Comment: The exchanges are guaranteed to be declared within rabbitmq when your callbacks are triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closures is a solution to keep the code async:

```
def declare_exchanges(self):
    exchange = "exchangeA"
    callback = self.on_exchange(exchange)
    channel.exchange_declare(callback=callback, exchange=exchange)

    exchange = "exchangeB"
    callback = self.on_exchange(exchange)
    channel.exchange_declare(callback=callback, exchange=exchange)

def on_exchange(self, exchange):
    def callback(response):
        print(exchange)

    return callback
```

PS: I opened an issue upstream, https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/898

Answer (score 1):

You could chain your callbacks accordingly to control the setup process. Just build your exchanges and queues step by step. This is more verbose but you keep control.

```
class ChatServer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.channel_in = None
        self.channel_out = None
        cred = pika.PlainCredentials('guest','guest')
        param = pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost',
                                          port=5672,
                                          virtual_host='/',
                                          credentials=cred)
        self.connection = pika.SelectConnection(param,self.on_connected)


    def on_connected(self, connection):
        self.connection.channel(self.on_channel_out_open)

    def on_channel_out_open(self,channel):
        self.channel_out = channel
        self.channel_out.exchange_declare(exchange='chatserver_out',
                                          type='direct',
                                          auto_delete=False,
                                          callback=self.on_exchange_declare_out)
    def on_exchange_declare_out(self,method_frame):
        self.channel_out.exchange_declare(exchange='cmd',
                                          type='direct',
                                          auto_delete=False,
                                          callback=self.on_exchange_declare_cmd_out)
    def on_exchange_declare_cmd_out(self,method_frame):
        # now all exchanges are defined.
        # Let's create the queues.
        # ...
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to wait for all exchanges before creating queues. That would defeat the point of an asynchronous interface.

Comment: If it is only for startup initialization, I'd go my way. So you are creating exchanges not only on startup but throughout the life cycle of the program ?

Comment: But your solution is still synchronized/delayed. It contradicts the callback nature of the SelectConnection. There must have been some kind of idea behind the asynchronous callback architecture?

Comment: It does not. This is only initialization. As soon as you are done declaring your exchanges your program will run forever firing off basic_publishes and receive lot's of messages through basic_consume. That's the relevant asynchronous part of the program not the setup of exchanges which is only executed once on startup.

Comment: Hm, but then the rest of the interface could have been much easier by making it synchronous. Now I must keep a counter state so I know how many times the on_exchange callback was called. But this is not the place to argue or complain. Thank you, even though the answer seems to be "it is impossible".

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be impossible to read the exchange name in the `exchange_declare` callback. What you need to do is instead to keep a counter so you know when all your exchanges are created:

```
class ...:
  def __init__(self):
    self.exchangestocreate = 2

  #...

  def declare_exchanges(self):
    channel.exchange_declare(callback=self.on_exchange, exchange="exchangeA")
    channel.exchange_declare(callback=self.on_exchange, exchange="exchangeB")

  def on_exchange(self, response):
    self.exchangestocreate -= 1
    if self.exhangestocreate == 0:
      # Declare bindings here
```

This will effectively make the interface synchronous in the exchange declaration step.